# Bind control left click

Tags: key-bindings

I want to be able to jump to definition with control left click when editing c++ code. I tried

```
(define-key c++-mode-map [C-mouse-1] 'rtags-find-symbol-at-point)
```

This does not seem to work because emacs (24.5.1) already define a global behavior for C-mouse-1 (buffer navigation in graphical mode). The contextual window opens, but rtags-find-symbol-at-point is not called.
Any way to make this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
(define-key c++-mode-map [C-down-mouse-1] 'rtags-find-symbol-at-point)
```

Comment: If you do `f1 k` then hold control and click it tells you that you pressed `C-down-mouse-1`, so this is probably what you should bind.

Comment: @dshepherd what is `f1 k`?

Comment: @sid-kap I meant press the `F1` key, then press the `k` key.

Answer (score 2):

For me the `C-down-mouse-1` solution worked, but still used the point from before the click. Thus I use now:

```
(define-key c-mode-base-map [C-down-mouse-1] 'mouse-drag-region)
(define-key c-mode-base-map [C-mouse-1] 'rtags-find-symbol-at-point)
```

so now, first the point gets set, then we find the correct symbol.